Which date shall I use for incremental refresh in Power BI: Invoice Date or Last Modified Date?
I would like to know which date shall I use to perform incremental refresh on my sales invoice table in power bi?
Invoice Date: Date when an order get invoiced. this date can be in the future as use a logic for orders which have not been invoiced such as requested delivery date = invoice date. This is the date we use to report sales.
Last Modified Date: Date when a row is last modified.
Looking forward to your input,
Kevin

Use the Last Modified Date for incremental refresh in Power BI. This date captures all changes, ensuring that updates and new data are included efficiently in the refresh.
